# How to auto populate email address in text field using extjs 4.1?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have done application using Extjs4.1, it contains feature login page. for email address and password field using text box field. **Here i need to add feature, auto populating of email address who recently visited.** In other application like java etc it is default property populates email address in text box field. **Can any tell me is it possible or not in extjs? How to achieve this one ?** great appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: turn on autocomplete and let the browser store it for you. you'll have to search my answers, but there is one on how to turn on autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to config more as part this feature, You can able to refer below link, which contain demo.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/forum-search.html

I hope this will help.

Thanks.